# Unable to Pause an animated SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vivus

I created an animated SVG using vivus instant ,added a button to pause but unable to get pause.
https://jsfiddle.net/zs0vgxya

```js
function f() {
  document.getElementById("svg8").pauseAnimations()
}
```

Comment: Your JsFiddle appear empty to me. Could you create a stack overflow snippet insead ?

Comment: In your new fiddle, your selector is false -> `svg` to `svg8`. And could you update the question with the new jsfiddle link

Comment: pausing SMIL will not pause CSS animations.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/56y4wo8j/1/

Comment: Please do not post a new JSFiddle link for every change, or at least delete the previous ones from your question and comments. Better yet; learn to include the code in your SO question: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/